# Drop a schema using variable name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following:

```
DECLARE @SchemaName NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SchemaName = 'MySchema'

DROP SCHEMA MySchema
```

How should I go to use the variable?
I tried `DROP SCHEMA OBJECT_ID(@SchemaName)`

Maybe `DELETE FROM SYS.SCHEMAS WHERE NAME = @SchemaName` equals a `DROP`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max), @SchemaName NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SchemaName = 'MySchema'

set @sql = 'DROP SCHEMA ' + quotename(@SchemaName)

---print @sql
exec sp_executesql(@sql)
```

Comment: Perfect because I already have a @sql that I can use to add this. (using COALESCE)

Answer (score 3):

Try using Dynamic sql

```
DECLARE @SchemaName NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SchemaName = 'test'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(128)= ''

SET @sql = 'DROP SCHEMA ' + quotename(@SchemaName) + ''

--print @sql
EXEC (@sql)
```

Also i don't think you can delete a record from `SYS.SCHEMAS` view

Comment: I think you probably want `EXEC (@sql)` rather than `EXEC @sql`, also, it is a good idea to use `QUOTENAME()` rather than manually concatenating brackets, as `QUOTENAME()` will escape characters properly. Consider the following schema - `CREATE SCHEMA "Stupid[]Name";` -- Using quotename would escape this correctly to give: [Stupid[]]Name], whereas just concatenating brackets will give [Stupid[]Name], resulting in a syntax error. While I admit this is an abhorrent object name, but sometimes people need to cater for this.

Comment: @GarethD - Agreed!!. Updated :)