# How to reference postgres variables as variables, not as literals

Tags: postgresql

I'm highly confused about the use of variables in postgres.
From the psql command-line, I've executed:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  NEW_SCHEMA          TEXT:= 'myschema';
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'Value of NEW_SCHEMA: %', NEW_SCHEMA;  -- A

  DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS NEW_SCHEMA;               -- B
  CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS NEW_SCHEMA;         -- C

END$$;
```

Gives me:

```
NOTICE:  Value of NEW_SCHEMA: myschema
NOTICE:  schema "new_schema" does not exist, skipping
DO
```

... so... at `A`, `NEW_SCHEMA` is interpreted as a variable, but at `B` and `C`, it is interpreted as a literal, and a new schema called `NEW_SCHEMA` is created.

How do I can I get psql to interpret variables as variables, not as literals.

Comment: You need dynamic SQL for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you cannot use a variable with the DROP SCHEMA command. You have to construct some SQL Dynamically.  The answer seems to be given here.  No point in reinventing the wheel.  :-)

[Drop a schema using variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540419/drop-a-schema-using-variable-name)

Update: I tried the following using Dynamic SQL and it works. My conclusion is that the CREATE/DROP SCHEMA does not allow variables. I commented out the original lines to show the **dynamic** replacements.

```
do $$
DECLARE
  NEW_SCHEMA TEXT:= 'myschema';
--  SQL TEXT := '';
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'Value of NEW_SCHEMA: %', NEW_SCHEMA; -- A

--  DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS NEW_SCHEMA;                  -- B
--  CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS NEW_SCHEMA;      -- C

  EXECUTE 'DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS ' || NEW_SCHEMA;
  EXECUTE 'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ' || NEW_SCHEMA;

END$$;
```

Comment: This refers to sql-server, not Postgres

Comment: Good point (I did not notice that), but that does not mean it does not apply to Postgres also.  Have you tried ?  :-)

Comment: Good grief...  when the cure is worse than the disease.

Copy and paste it is then. :-/    Thanks.

Comment: Cure is above.  Don't thank me for the 20 mins work.  :-)

Comment: My apologies  -- and thanks for the reply. I'm grumbling at (yet another) linguistic horror of SQL, not your solution.

I was hoping to use variables to clean up and modularize a messy installation script. Again, SQL fights you all the way. Hmmppph.

Comment: FYI it's nothing to do with CREATE/DROP commands specifically; you cannot use a variable for an identifier, i.e. a schema, table, column, etc. If you want to do that, then you will always need dynamic sql.

Comment: Thanks -- I learned this in 1995 and forget about it. I was hoping, things had progressed.